# ojalgo : How to sort each row of a matrix?

Tags: java, sorting, matrix, ojalgo

I have a question about using the oj algo library,

I would like to know if there is an easy and efficient way to take a row out of a Primitive64Matrix, sort it, and then replace it in the matrix,
Or alternatively to sort each row of a Primitive64Matrix (but even then I would still like to know how to fill a row of a matrix efficiently)

Here is what I'm doing now :

```
        final double[][] tab = {
            {
                1, 3, 4, 2 },
            {
                0, 4, 3, 1 } };
        Primitive64Matrix matrix = Primitive64Matrix.FACTORY.rows(tab);
        for (int iRow = 0; iRow < matrix.countRows(); iRow++) {
            final double[] rowSorted = matrix.row(iRow).toRawCopy1D();

            Arrays.sort(rowSorted);
            final Primitive64Matrix.DenseReceiver receiver = matrix.copy();
            receiver.fillRow(iRow, Primitive64Matrix.FACTORY.rows(rowSorted));
            matrix = receiver.get();
        }
```

I think it's ugly and surely they must be other more efficient ways to do that (especially the .copy is awful)

Answer (score 0):

`Primitive64Matrix` is immutable. Maybe you'll find it more natural to work with the various classes in the `org.ojalgo.matrix.store` package. Further, `Primitive64Matrix` has been renamed `MatrixR064` in newer versions.

Here something you can do, that is close to what you're currently doing:

```
    double[][] tab = { { 1, 3, 4, 2 }, { 0, 4, 3, 1 } };
    MatrixR064 matrix = MatrixR064.FACTORY.rows(tab);

    DenseReceiver receiver = matrix.copy();

    ArrayR064 temp = ArrayR064.make(matrix.getColDim());

    for (RowView<Double> view : matrix.rows()) {
        view.supplyTo(temp.data);
        Arrays.sort(temp.data);
        receiver.fillRow(view.row(), temp);
    }

    matrix = receiver.get();
```

If you use `Primitive64Store` (not yet renamed) instead of `MatrixR064` you can avoid copying the matrix, but still do essentially the same thing as above.

```
    double[][] tab = { { 1, 3, 4, 2 }, { 0, 4, 3, 1 } };
    Primitive64Store matrix = Primitive64Store.FACTORY.rows(tab);

    ArrayR064 temp = ArrayR064.make(matrix.getColDim());

    for (RowView<Double> view : matrix.rows()) {
        view.supplyTo(temp.data);
        Arrays.sort(temp.data);
        matrix.fillRow(view.row(), temp);
    }
```